# SQL Adding Ids to foreign key id

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

```
Create Table ProductCategory(ProductCategory_ID int IDENTITY Primary Key,   
                             ProductCategory varchar(50))

Insert Into Product(ProductCategory)
Select pc.ProductCategory
From ProductCategory pc left join Product p
on p.Category = pc.ProductCategory
Group By p.Category
Order By p.Category

Alter Table Product
Add Constraint FK_ProductCategoryID
Foreign Key (ProductCategoryID)
References ProductCategory(ProductCategory_ID)
```

Supposedly when I do this:

```
    Select p.ProductCategoryID
    From Product p
```

It should give me the IDs of the Categories from the "ProductCategory" table.  But it just gives me NULL
And when I do:

```
Select *
From ProductCategory
```

I get all the proper IDs and categories.  Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Explain why you think you need to join here.

Comment: First of all this is SQL server and not mysql and you haven't shown your product table

Comment: Any error when you run your `INSERT INTO` statement? I'd have thought you'd want to run an `UPDATE` statement to update `Product.ProductCategory`, instead of inserting rows with just the `ProductCategory` field populated, and all other fields either set to their defaults or null.

Answer (score 0):

Run this and see what you get

```
Select pc.ProductCategory
From ProductCategory pc 
left join Product p
       on p.Category = pc.ProductCategory
Group By p.Category
Order By p.Category
```